# C# WCF and certificate FaultException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wcf, certificate

I would like to implement WCF service with server and client certificates.

When I try to connect to service on IIS I get the following error:

> Test method
>   TestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
>   threw exception: 
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException:
>   Secure channel cannot be opened
>   because security negotiation with the
>   remote endpoint has failed. This may
>   be due to absent or incorrectly
>   specified EndpointIdentity in the
>   EndpointAddress used to create the
>   channel. Please verify the
>   EndpointIdentity specified or implied
>   by the EndpointAddress correctly
>   identifies the remote endpoint.  ---> 
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   The request for security token has
>   invalid or malformed elements..

My web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="DotNetStoreBinding" receiveTimeout="00:00:15">
             <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:00:20" />
             <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
             </security>
          </binding>
       </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WcfServiceCustumer.Service1">
            <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceCustumer.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" findValue="CN=DotNetStore" />
                    <clientCertificate>
                      <certificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" findValue="CN=Bob"/>
                      <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
                    </clientCertificate>
                </serviceCredentials>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

After I have created server I created new project and added service reference. I call the service like this:

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(
        new Uri("http://localhost/CustomerServiceSite/Customer.svc"),
        EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("DotNetStore"),
        new AddressHeaderCollection()
    );

WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;

var client = new CustomerService.Service1Client(binding, address);

client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN=Bob");

IList<Product> allProducts = client.GetAllProducts();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is a server name DotNetStore? Try to use server name as dns identity on the client. Also set httpsGetEnabled = false (but it is not source of your problem).

Comment: Is server name my computers name? My service is available on http://localhost/CustomerServiceSite/Customer.svc so I suppose I should use "localhost" DNS identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was occuring becouse of certificates. I did not have correct pairs on client and service.

A good description how to correctly use certificates can be found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/9StepsWCF.aspx?msg=3181718